# How to set local notification time to time on date picker for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uidatepicker

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myDatePicker1: UIDatePicker!
    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "This is a notification"
        content.subtitle = "I hope this works"
        content.body = "from the tutorial"
        content.badge = 1

        let componentsFromDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: myDatePicker1.date)

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: componentsFromDate, repeats: true)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timeDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in})
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Here is what showed in the console when I printed the request and trigger:

```
<UNNotificationRequest: 0x6000002335e0; identifier: timeDone, content:
 <UNNotificationContent: 0x600000113ef0; title: This is a notification,
 subtitle: I hope this works, body: from the tutorial,
 categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , peopleIdentifiers: ( ),
 threadIdentifier: , attachments: ( ), badge: 1, sound: (null),
 hasDefaultAction: YES, defaultActionTitle: (null),
 shouldAddToNotificationsList: YES,
 shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground: NO, shouldLockDevice: NO,
 shouldPauseMedia: NO, isSnoozeable: NO, fromSnooze: NO,
 darwinNotificationName: (null), darwinSnoozedNotificationName: (null),
 trigger: <UNCalendarNotificationTrigger: 0x600000233540;
 dateComponents: <NSDateComponents: 0x6000003461a0>
     Calendar: <CFCalendar 0x60000009c7a0 [0x10c9fee40]>{identifier = 'gregorian'}
     TimeZone: America/Vancouver (PDT) offset -25200 (Daylight)
     Era: 1
     Calendar Year: 2017
     Month: 8
     Leap month: no
     Day: 11
     Hour: 9
     Minute: 58
     Second: 39
     Nanosecond: 0
     Quarter: 0
     Year for Week of Year: 2017
     Week of Year: 32
     Week of Month: 2
     Weekday: 6
     Weekday Ordinal: 2, repeats: YES>>
```

I am new to app development with Swift and am trying to create a simple app that sends the user a local notification when at the time they select on a date picker. For some reason, the `UNCalenderNotificationTrigger` will only take `DateComponents()` and `DateComponents()` must be an Int, and not a type `Date()` (from the date picker). Could someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Please show us some code about what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `DateComponents` from a `Date` object using a `Calendar` using

```
let componentsFromDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: Date())
```

If you replace `Date()` with your `Date` object from the `DatePicker`, you can use the `componentsFromDate` to create the `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but for some reason this did not work... the error message I got was "cannot convert value of type "DateComponents" to type 'TimeInterval' (aka Double)". 

Comment: Are you even using `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`? That sound like you are using a `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`.

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right. I was doing that. However, I fixed it now and there are no errors, yet for some reason, in the simulator, there is no notification firing. The code above is not updated to the calendar trigger instead of the time interval trigger. Is there something else I am doing wrong that is preventing this from working. Thanks for all your help so far by the way. I am learning lots 

Comment: In the completion handler of `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(` you should print the request to see it added successfully and print its next trigger date as well, to see what might go wrong. Have you been able to deliver notifications successfully before, are you sure your `UNNotificationCenter` is set up correctly?

Comment: Now the badge shows up... but no notification. I printed the request and trigger, and this is what it gives me (seems okay to me, but what do I know). Oh, it was too long for a comment, so I put it under the code above.

Comment: You need to set up the `sound` parameter of the notification content as well.

Comment: I don't know how to do that... could you kindly show me? Also, I did a tutorial which just used a time interval for the trigger of the notification, and it worked, although it did not have sound.

Comment: Just write `content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()`

Comment: I did it, but it did not work... the badge appears though. Whaaaat??